# Restrict Integer value in the django urls

Tags: django

I have the following Django URL, which allows users to register for any one security code from 1 to 6.

```
path('add/<int:security_code>/', security_views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='register_code'),
```

Url should render the template up to 6 security codes such as

```
https://www.example.com/add/1/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/2/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/3/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/4/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/5/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/6/ #-- It should work
https://www.example.com/add/7/ #-- It should throw 404 when the user types a number greater than 6.
```

What change I would need to do to restrict URL for limited codes, it should throw a 404 or bad request error if the user manually puts a different number. I don't want to modify the view as I would need to add the `get` as well as the `post`  methods.

```
from django.views import generic
from core import models

class RegisterView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = models.SecurityCode
    fields = ['name', 'code']
```

Is there any way we can do it without modifying the `views` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [**`re_path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) to specify a regular expression:

```
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(
    'add/(?P<security_code>[1-6])/$',
    security_views.RegisterView.as_view(),
    name='register_code'
),
```